# Chrome Extension - how to detect a page update and reload the extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

As you may have noticed, some pages like Facebook, Twitter - when you scroll to the bottom, the page adds more content to the bottom. This makes the page longer, the scroll bar longer. However, my chrome extension has already done it's stuff on the page content loaded initially. I want my extension to detect that there has been an update on the page and either reload itself, or at least allow me to call some more code, so I can apply whatever changes to the new content on the page. Is this possible? I've tried searching for help, but nothing seems to cover this specific situation, unless I've missed it!

Any help would be great.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508954) for a compilation of various methods. For the scenario you've described there is no extension-specific API so you can use the standard DOM methods in the content script e.g. MutationObserver, site-specific DOM events, timer-based polling, etc.

Comment: I'll check it, thank you!